# Syntax error in DATA statement

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77, g77

I have this code in a Fortran project:

```
ITEGER IV, IY
DIMENSION IV(NTAB,IDEPTH)
DIMENSION IY(IDEPTH)
DATA IV,IY /(IDEPTH*NTAB)*0,IDEPTH*0)/
```

Attempting to compile the project generates this error:

```
    DATA IV,IY /(IDEPTH*NTAB)*0,IDEPTH*0)/
                1

Syntax error in DATA statement at (1).
```

This worked under f77/g77 (gcc 4.1), but a recent upgrade has moved us to gcc 4.4 and gfortran. Now this code is causing errors but I just can't see the problem.

Comment: There are multiple typos in your code... Please fix them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this was an extension to the Standard, which is not supported any more. The [FORTRAN 77 Standard, ch. 9.1](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf-9.html#sh-9.1) states that the repeat value shall be a

> nonzero, unsigned, integer constant or the symbolic name of such a
>   constant.

As such, the `IDEPTH*NTAB` is not allowed as repeat value.

You can circumvent this by using another constant that constitutes the product:

```
      PROGRAM test
        INTEGER IV, IY
        INTEGER,PARAMETER :: NTAB=1,IDEPTH=1
        INTEGER,PARAMETER :: PROD=NTAB*IDEPTH

        DIMENSION IV(NTAB,IDEPTH)
        DIMENSION IY(IDEPTH)

        DATA IV,IY /PROD*0,IDEPTH*0/
      END
```

Or, to make it strictly FORTRAN 77 compliant:

```
      PROGRAM test
        INTEGER IV, IY
        INTEGER NTAB,IDEPTH
        INTEGER PROD

        PARAMETER (NTAB=1,IDEPTH=1)
        PARAMETER (PROD=NTAB*IDEPTH)

        DIMENSION IV(NTAB,IDEPTH)
        DIMENSION IY(IDEPTH)

        DATA IV,IY /PROD*0,IDEPTH*0/
      END
```